# Mobile web app : Using same set of images in multiple resolution devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I would like to know, if I can maintain a single CSS file for my mobile web app. The web app is targeted for different resolution of android devices. So i would like to know can i use same set of images and scale it down using any CSS styles, rather than keeping multiple images for each resolutions ? The webapp is built using html5, css3 and javascript.

I know we can use css media queries, but through that i will need to load different images based on the device width. I am trying to use same images for all resolution of devices. If i keep a high resolution image overall in the code.

Is this possible ? please let me know.

Thanks in advance. Appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .element { background-image: url(../images/bg1.img); }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
 .element { background-image: url(../images/bg2.img); }
}
```

but you can also set it to maybe 100% (If it should fit the screen on any size)

Comment: Hi,I would like to know can we use the same image for both device of max:width 480 px and min width:800px ?? In the above post i see there are two images bg1 and bg2. Can i use only 1 image for both ?

Comment: yes of course! you can change only the size with $("img").css("width","100px");

Comment: It doesnt work as the height also will be different.

Comment: the height scales automatically... or if you want to  $("img").css({"width":"100px", "height":"10px"});